# solr dismax lower boost for empty values

Tags: sorting, solr, dismax

I have a SOLR document which looks like this:

```
<doc>
    <float name="score">1.7004467</float>
    <str name="name">Love</str>
    <str name="id">15801637</str>
    <int name="itemCount">3</int>
    <date name="last_modified">2012-08-10T11:04:28Z</date>
    <str name="emailaddress"/>
</doc>

<doc>
    <str name="name">Love</str>
    <str name="id">158015757</str>
    <int name="itemCount">3</int>
    <date name="last_modified">2012-08-10T11:04:28Z</date>
    <str name="emailaddress">xxx@yy.com</str>
</doc>
```

I want to write a query that matches documents by name, but boost records with `emailaddress` to appear on top, and without `emailaddress` toward the bottom.

I don't want to sort by email address. I prefer using dismax (i am presenting a simplified problem here).

Comment: Thanks you . but,It didn't work . But when i put a specific email address like bq=emailaddress:xxx@yy.com^2. it shows doc with email on top . i have a related question . when i see <str name="emailaddress"/> in result, does this mean its empty /null ? need to add something to "[* TO *]" to eliminate blank/novalue records.

Comment: Can i use range query on field type of string

Comment: the below would work as it would select only fields with values and it is a range query.

Answer (score 0):

Check e.g. [Boost Score](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents) OR If you are using Dismax parser check for parameter [Boost Query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bq_.28Boost_Query.29)

`emailaddress:[* TO *]` should cover with emailaddress having values

For your condition you can try `bq=emailaddress:[* TO *]^2.0`